how does a long USB cable affect power bank output
Being a tyro at this stuff, this might seem stupid, but here goes:
I’m a Raynaud’s sufferer, big time, so this is pretty important to me, though it might not seem so at first glance.
I have a product (heated gloves) that comes with 5V batteries, which have such low capacity as to render the product useless for my purposes.  I chose these gloves because the glove manufacturer says I can use any 5V/1A power pack.  They do say that the power bank must deliver 1A output.
I don’t understand how, but I gather that a power pack can limit its output amperage with some internal circuitry (a resistor?), since I have a power pack with both a 1A and a 2.1A USB-A port.
In order to use a higher-capacity power bank, because of its size, I need to strap the power bank to my arm (awkward) or put it in an inside pocket of my coat (much preferred), so I thought I could get a USB-A M-F extension cable for that purpose.  But if I understand anything at all about DC, it’s that the length of the delivery wire (as well as its diameter and materials) affects the current, which is to say that the wire has resistance, so I’m wondering just how adding the extension cable would meaningfully affect my scheme:

is it noise? or would it matter enough that I should not get a 3’ cord, but strap the pack to my arm with a shorter cable ?
Would it offer enough resistance to allow me to use the 2.1A port even though the glove literature states that I should use a 1A output on a 5V power bank. (It’s getting harder to find power banks with 1A output ports.)
How could I tell ?  I have an ohmmeter but I have no idea how I’d use it on an USB cable since I don’t understand the jacks at each end.  And in any case, I have no idea how to determine the resistances in the gloves at their various settings, which leads to another set of questions (assuming I need to figure this out because it’s not just noise):

The gloves have 3 heat settings.  If gather that the different settings mean different circuitry within the gloves to determine the amount of heat generated within.  Does anyone know how they do this?  3 different diameters of wires (smaller->more heat generated for the same amperage?) or one set of wires but something internal that causes the glove to draw more amps?  I’m guessing more likely the latter, but I can’t test it with my multimeter because I don’t know how to get the multimeter between the power bank and the glove (where in the USB-A connection is the power line?). By the way, the USB-A’s plastic insert is white so I assume it’s USB 1.0, whatever that means for this purpose.  In any case, what I’m wondering is if I could use the 2.1A output port if only on the a certain heat setting.  Another way to put this question might be this: if the gloves control the amperage drawn, then why would I have to use the right battery port (1A max)?
Finally: I see that the marketing lit for some power banks say things like “intelligent” or “over-charge protection” or “over-voltage protection” and I wonder if any of those things would help, or are they only apropos to the input side of the battery ?

Being a tyro at this stuff: sorry, but what's a "tyro"?

Your outlets provide 20A; that doesn't mean all light bulbs use 2500W; drawing less current than a source's rating is fine, drawing more is not. Other random notes: the color of USB hardware is not specified and no firm conclusions should be draw from a white, orange, blue or black connector. The glove's power setting is (99% likely) achieved by PWM: "blinking" the heater on and off to deliver less power than max over time. Lastly, you don't need any power bank protection feature to use your gloves safely.

tyro, per merriam-webster: beginner in learning; novice. Thx for the comments.

@tyro thanks! I've learned a new word today :)

You are probably overthinking this but it's impossible to say for sure without knowing the internal design of the gloves. The 5V/1A figure is doable with just about any USB power bank you can find these days; I'm pretty sure the cheap ones you find as swag at trade shows can all do at least 1A, and 5V is the USB standard so no problem there.
Some things like computer USB ports or unpowered hubs may not support 1A, but there is no danger in selecting a port that can supply more than 1A; it won't force that current into the load. Ditto higher voltage capability - that must be negotiated/requested by the receiving device and yours won't.
I'm not sure what connection the gloves or their controller box use to attach to the external power bank (short USB-A plug? Type B socket?) but 1A is still a fairly low current, even for USB-A which was never really designed for the high power applications that e.g. USB-C is. Standard 6ft/2m cables should work just fine. If you're concerned about excessive voltage drop due to the internal resistance (I wouldn't be), then you can search for "22 AWG" variants of whichever cable you need, which will give you conductors more than adequate for the task.

Thank you very much. The gloves have a male USB 1.x (white) jack (not a type-B plug).  I gather that the resistance of the USB cable would not matter, esp if I get one that's rated for USB 3.x.  That's helpful.

What I don't understand is why they (manufacturer) make such a big deal of using only a 1A delivery port from a battery.  Is it just a cover-their-behinds kind of thing?  Or is there really something to it?  In web searches I see conflicting arguments about whether the consumer can draw more than it needs and thus damage itself.  This is all over my head.

I have found info about the power specs for USB 1.0 (and the pinout) but I haven't read the whole spec (duh) but it's confusing me more than ever.  It says for USB 1.x: max current 500 mA, max power 2.5V, max voltage 5V.  If those are MAXIMA, then how can a power bank with a white (USB 1.x) jack be labelled 1A?  or 2.1A? Wouldn't that violate the spec?  What does compliance even mean in that case?

AFAIK under USB 1.x, the device negotiates current draw in 100mA steps up to 500mA. As USB became more of a de facto low voltage DC power supply standard, that current limit was progressively raised. 1.5A is I believe the most that a USB A socket is required to supply, but that is routinely exceeded. You used to see a lot of this with people plugging their phones into devices that couldn't supply enough current and not having them charge.

Thanks for the enlightenment.  So the standard means “at least” X amps, not MAX X amps, I gather.  So much for standards.
